# How to ignore angularjs routes for WebAPI help pages?

Tags: angularjs, routes

I'm using the following state configuration:

```
app.config(["$stateProvider", "$urlRouterProvider", "$locationProvider",
    function ($stateProvider, $urlRouterProvider, $locationProvider) {

        $urlRouterProvider.otherwise('/home');

        $stateProvider
            .state("home", {
                url: "/home",
               views: {
                   '': {
                        templateUrl: "Scripts/app/common/views/home.html",
                        controller: 'homeController'
                   }
                },
            data: {}
        })

         ...
        $locationProvider.html5Mode(true);
    }
]);
```

And some server WebAPI help pages are not working because the following PATHs are used:

/Help/Api

/Help/Api/POST-api-Get-Users

/Help/ResourceModel?modelName=User

etc.

Currently help pages are not working, and I don't want to add to angular the following states:
- url: "/Help"
- url: "/Help/Api"
etc.

Is there a way to simple ignore all angular states started with "/Help*"? I want to have client angular pages and the same time server pages too. And I don't want to have two different master pages (one with angular, and another without).

Comment: do you mean that you don't want a certain service or something to run? it's not entirely clear what you want...